# `binary_crossentropy` definitions not the same?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In my neural network if I compile it with:

```
D.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt_D)
```

it works great but if I do:

```
def make_loss_D(c):
    def loss_D(y_true, y_pred):
        #return c * K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true)
        return c * K.mean (K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true))
    return loss_D

D.compile(loss=[make_loss_D(c=1.0)], optimizer=opt_D)
```

The losses are totally different, and the neural network makes very strong predictions close to 1 or 0 always.

I like the behaviour seen in the first example, but after digging into https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py code I don't see why the two would be so different. Adjusting the value of `c` in my code to make the two losses match after the first epoch doesn't help at all.

What is the difference in the losses defined, and why is the second one so badly behaved?

Edit:

After fixing the order of `y_pred`, `y_true`, and axis for mean, the custom function also works.

```
def make_loss_D(c):
    def loss_D(y_true, y_pred):
        return c * K.mean (K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
    return loss_D
```

<s>The losses are still not the same,  what could be the reason for that?</s>

Comment: Which version of Keras are you using? After 2.0.7, you have to use `K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)` instead of `K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true)`.

Comment: 2.0.8! Thanks for the catch! I fixed it but I still don't get exactly the same losses..

Comment: After the edit: how different are the losses? Have you taken care to make two models with the exact same weights? (Weights are initialized randomly, and you will never create two models that render the same results).

Comment: I found that the training was with different optimizers, now they are identical. I re-set the numpy random seed every time, but I didn't check if I get identical initial weights